# compile c file in uwp

Tags: c, uwp, win-universal-app

I would like to compile a file c, I get the following error:

> cannot compile c file with /ZW option

I removed the option in the file properties (Windows Runtime extension), but I still have the same error.
Thank you

Comment: You likely turned off ``/ZW`` for a different configuration/platform than the one you are building. Make sure you set "Consume Windows Runtime Extensions = No" for _All configurations_ and _All platforms_ for your ``.c`` file(s).

Comment: thank you so much I forgot to enter for All configurations and All Platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing project properties in Visual Studio, remember often need to set **Configuration** *All Configurations* and **Platform** to *All Platforms*. This can be particularly confusing when you are changing the properties of the non-active configuration/platform and your changes don't seem to have any effect.

> Note that you can use C language files in a UWP project, but you can't consume Windows Runtime APis using C. C++ is required for both C++/CX language extensions as well as the new C++ WinRT language projections.